# Можно ли с помощью скрипта сделать, чтобы блок не показывался в разметке браузера не удаляя его из html?

Tags: javascript

На сайт подключена версия для слабовидящих и при переходе на нее пропадают изображения из-за одного блока. Есть ли возможность не удаляя этот блок, силами скрипта, спрятать этот блок в браузере?

[В браузере так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8wfF.png)

[А нужно так](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnpAR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что подразумевается под "не удаляя этот блок, силами скрипта, спрятать этот блок в браузере", т.к. на втором скриншоте он именно удалён, но попробуйте присвоить ему стиль

```
 display: none;
```

из скрипта это можно сделать инлайновым стилем

```
div.style.display = 'none';
```

где div - элемент, который требуется скрыть

Comment: Спасибо! Не думала, что этот вариант подойдет поэтому его и не рассматривала )), все работает.